# Call a function, only when others functions are loaded (JS/TS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, callback, ionic3

I'm building an app with Ionic Framework 3. I was wondering if it possible to call a function, only when others functions are loaded. I made a simplified version of my code:

```
getNumberOne() {
    //CODE TO GET NUMBER ONE//
    this.getGraph; //CAUSE I WANT TO LOAD MY GRAPH//
}

getNumberTwo() {
    //CODE TO GET NUMBER TWO//
    this.getGraph; //CAUSE I WANT TO LOAD MY GRAPH//
}

getOtherData() {
    getOtherDataOne() {
        //CODE TO GET NUMBER//
        this.getGraph; //CAUSE I WANT TO LOAD MY GRAPH//
    }

    getOtherDataTwo() {
        //CODE TO GET NUMBER//
        this.getGraph; //CAUSE I WANT TO LOAD MY GRAPH//
    }
}

getGraph() {
   //CODE TO LOAD THE GRAPH//
}
```

In my example, the function "getGraph" is fired 4 times, but in my real code, it fire 42 times. Aonther point you need to know is that each function is not linked. I mean that getNumberOne() is not sure to sucess, cause if it doesn't get a number, then it return an error.

That's why I dont think that I cant just put function in function like this:

```
getNumberOne() {
/*Function to query*/
  .then((sucess) => {
    getNumberTwo() {
        /*Function to query*/
          .then((sucess) => {
            getOtherData() {
                getOtherDataOne() {
                        /*Function to query*/
                          .then((sucess) => {
                getOtherDataTwo() {
                        /*Function to query*/
                          .then((sucess) => {
                             this.getGraph; //CAUSE I WANT TO LOAD MY GRAPH//
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
}

getGraph() {
    //CODE TO LOAD THE GRAPH//
}
```

Is there a way to optimize this?

Comment: Does your codebase allow for async/await? Seems like it's the perfect solution.

Example:
    const numberOne = await getNumberOne();
    const numberTwo = await getNumberTwo();
    ...
    const dataTwo = getOtherDataTwo();
    if (dataTwo !== null) {
      this.getGraph();
   }

Comment: That's a good idea. I started searching on the net, but I'm not sure of how async/await works... Can you explain me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at promises in javascript. In particular, seems like you want to wait on multiple promises to finish before doing something. You should use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all([getNumberOne(), getNumberTwo()]).then((values) => {
  this.getGraph(); 
});
```

`async` function and `await` is just a simplified way of writing promises. So you can rewrite the above as:

```
async myAsyncFunc(){
    await Promise.all([getNumberOne(), getNumberTwo()]);
    this.getGraph();
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want getNumberOne and getNumberTwo functions to run serially, simply do this:

```
async myAsyncFunc(){
    await getNumberOne();
    await getNumberTwo();
    this.getGraph();
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! :)

Comment: That work!

But, is it possible to stop the code until resolve() is called? Cause right now, even if getNumberOne() isn't completly loaded, getNumberTwo() starts...

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Do you want them to run serially? In that case see my edits above.